# 18.04 WiFi BCM43142 no work after upgrade

Tags: 18.04, wireless, broadcom

Recently, maybe after some upgrade, My laptop BCM43142 WiFi does not work.
I can confirm that two months ago it worked on 18.04. I have tried
`apt update; apt upgrade` and reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source package,
but not work, no kernel module wl  is installed.
I also checked in the Dual OS Win10, Yes, the WiFi worked.
If plug in network cable, the wire network connected.

In System settings >> WiFi section, it display: "no WiFi adapter found"

For detailed log, please refer to this [link](https://pastebin.com/Uy0sUcpY) and Thanks!

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: It's a little strange of my OS, when I ran: sudo mokutil --sb-state , it displayed: EFI variables are not supported on this system. I think my OS running on BIOS mode, no EFI because no /sys/firmware/efi  file exist.  and I checked in BIOS, no "secure boot" option.

Comment: I also checked in the dual OS win10, "msinfo32" reported that the BIOS mode is legacy, and seem that the "Secure Boot" is only for EFI system

Comment: So what happens if you run `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`? Please post output to your question AS TEXT.

Comment: @Pilot6  Please refer to https://pastebin.com/UQMvcd0y     I can not paste too long log in the comment. I also rebooted the machine and $ lsmod |grep wl show nothing.

Comment: Don't past additional information to comments. [edit] your question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `bcmwl-kernel-source` doesn't build with the 4.15 kernel anymore.

I suggest upgrading kernel by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

It appeared that `gcc` is a wrong version to build this module.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out the root cause ! at last, I reinstall gcc to the latest 7.5.0,  (because I forgot that I had replaced gcc to old version for other project), and reinstall the bcwl-kernel-source, the WIFI immediately work ! Thank you very much, and you save me a whole day !